# Using Contact.GetContactInformation in Lync SDK doesn't return status

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2010, lync-client-sdk

I'm using the [Contact.GetContactInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh380108.aspx) method to attempt to pull a contact's availability information. The issue I'm running into is that it doesn't seem to be getting the correct information unless I actually go into Lync and have it refresh that user's current status (i.e. by searching their name so that Lync resolves their status).

It seems as though that method pulls information from some Lync cache and doesn't actually go find the latest information. How can I get the latest information for a contact in Lync, even if the contact is not in my list and Lync hasn't found their status information yet?

Answer (score 1):

You could try subscribing to ContactInformationChanged event and then catching the events from that. An active subscription to the contact details usually ensures you get the most up to date information back from the server. Will do a code example later today if/when I get time.